# Protractor text test with link

Tags: protractor

I was wondering how I would be able to test for text using Protractor when part of my text contains a link to a separate page.

Is there a way to expand the link and get the raw text to expect that?

Should I use something similar to:

```
expect(myText).toContain("Some text <a href="..."")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the text is a link, you can use following locator for the same

```
expect(element(by.linkText('Google')).getTagName()).toBe('a');
```

This is in case when link is like this in DOM

`<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>`

Source: [Software Automata - Protractor – Locators](https://softwareautomata.wordpress.com/2017/07/29/protractor-locators/)

Comment: Well, most of the text is just plain text with one word being a link to another page. I've already created a test to ensure that the link takes users to the correct place, but how can I ensure that the text in its entirety is what I expect?

Comment: I assume that it'll be something like this then `<div>Some Text <a>Link</a>and rest</div>`. If thats the case then yes, what you thought initially is the right way since capturing the text within `div` will also fetch the anchor tags.